# Simple Authentication in server-side Blazor apps

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I want to implement a simple authentication pattern in a server-side Blazor app. My goals are:

- Store the result from the authentication endpoint of a 3rd party product which returns, amongst other things, a bearer token to use for future API requests (this is not OIDC or a JWT)
- Validate the token (there is an API for doing this) the first time the app is loaded in a tab
- If the user is not logged in, or the token is invalid, redirect to a login page

Microsoft's documentation says to use ASP.NET Identity. This is a very heavy-weight solution and contains a mixture of Razor pages and Blazor components.

I've been experimenting over the past weekend and my first port of call was using `HttpContext` `SignInAsync` method which is what we have previously been using. This doesn't work in Blazor because of the way the updates are pushed via SignalR.

I went down a second path of creating a derived `RouteView`. This would probably work if `Render` was an `async` method, as if I need async to be able to read from the browser protected storage. I've been able to prove that the custom route view works when the information is hardcoded, but I'm not convinced that this will ever work because `Render` is not async.

I'd love to hear how you solved this problem.

Here is my code.

**App.razor**

```
@using Aproneers.Web.App.Components
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AppRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)"></AppRouteView>
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

**AppRouteView.cs**

```
    public class AppRouteView : RouteView
    {
        [Inject]
        public NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; set; }

        [Inject]
        public IAuthHelper AuthHelper { get; set; }

        protected void Render(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
        {
            var authorize = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(RouteData.PageType, typeof(AuthorizeAttribute)) != null;

            // TODO: Need to call AuthHelper.PopulateFromStorage() here
            // but because it is async and this is a void method it doesn't
            // work.

            if (authorize && AuthenticationService.User == null)
            {
                var reqUrl = WebUtility.UrlEncode(new Uri(NavigationManager.Uri).PathAndQuery);
                NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"auth/login?r={reqUrl}");
            }
            else
                base.Render(builder);
        }
    }
```

**AuthHelper.cs**

```
    public class AuthHelper : IAuthHelper
    {
        private ProtectedLocalStorage _store;

        public User User { get; private set; }

        public AuthHelper(ProtectedLocalStorage store)
        {
            _store = store;
        }

        public async Task PopulateFromStorage()
        {
            var result = await _store.GetAsync<User>("user");
            if (result.Success)
                User = result.Value;
        }

        public async Task Login(string username, string password)
        {
            var user = new User() { Name = username, Token = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() };
            await _store.SetAsync("user", User);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can achieve what you want using a Custom AuthenticationStateProvider and the standard `AuthorizeRouteView`.  Some questions before I try and answer.  If I read this correctly, you're going offsite to get your "token"?  Where does the offsite authenticator return to - which page?  Is "loginpage" on the Authenticator site?

Comment: If you are returning from an external service, you can use the HttpContext.SignInAsync from a controller method (to set the user), then redirect into your main blazor application. Basically intercepting the login return like an old style .net MVC project, then forwarding on to blazor.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis, yes, I call an API providing a username and password. The API returns a token that is used as a bearer token, along with information about the user such as their name and email address. It's not an offsite authenticator, the authentication happens via an API only.

Comment: Great.  I'll post an answer tomorrow.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis thanks heaps, I appreciate your time.